# Cypress - Como usar o dia atual como variável

Tags: javascript, testes, testes-automatizados, cypress

Estou testando um sistema, e preciso fazer algumas verificações em uma tabela, no qual uma das colunas mostra um texto acompanhado da data do dia atual. É possível ver o texto "**Gerado por Teste dia 20/12/2022**": https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8sQa.png

E atualmente, o código está assim:

```
cy.contains('td', 'Teste').should('be.visible');
cy.contains('td', 'Junho 2022').should('be.visible');
cy.contains('td', 'Gerado por Teste dia 20/12/2022').should('be.visible')
```

Mas obviamente, se eu rodar amanhã, dia 21, o teste irá falhar, caso eu não altere a data.
Minha dúvida é se é possível fazer a verificação sempre com o dia atual, utilizando alguma variável ou comando do Cypress.

Fiz alguns testes utilizando uma variável assim, mas não consigo encaixar no 'contains', já que ele contem uma parte de texto.

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
cy.contains('td', 'Gerado por Teste dia '.dayjs'').should('be.visible')
```

Comment: Cara, seguinte, isso é difícil de responder pois vai depender se o seu teste é de caixa preta, mas eu como desenvolvedor, faço o seguinte, eu faço uma conexão direta com o sgbd via uma lib de banco de dados, faço a query na mão usando sql puro direto na tabela que contém este dado que eu preciso "concatenar" o valor, e então eu faço a verificação. Se isso não for possível via o seu fluxo de trabalho  então eu recomendo fazer via requisições de API. Manda o POST com uma data, e dps verifica se o resultado é o esperado...enfim esses são meus dois centavos.

Comment: Se ngm responder com uma ideia melhor eu posso postar aqui depois de uma maneira mais detalhada.